# Can a Rigid Designator still exist if there is only one possible world?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, modal-logic, possible-worlds, kripke

According to Kripke, a rigid designator is a pronoun (but not all pronouns are rigid designators) and they pick out the same unique individual in each possible world. I understand this, however, if there is only one possible state of the world, can something lets say for example, Brittney - be a rigid designator?

Would love some help on this! Thanks!

Comment: If there is only one possible world then, by definition, any designator is rigid.